# why the output is different and what is the wrong in this code?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++98

so i have been trying to get the input of array's size and its elements then display the elements to the screen but when i for example put
array's size : 7
array's elements : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
```

The code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {    
    int n , Arr[n];    
    cout << "please put the size of the array " ;    
    cin >> n;    
    cout << "please enter array's elemets ";    
    for (int k=0; k<n ; k++) {    
        cin >> Arr[k];    
    }    
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){    
        cout << Arr[i] << endl;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: `int n , Arr[n];` is a bug. Actually more than 1 bug..

Comment: Simply why I can't do this ??

Comment: In standard c++ `n` must be known at compile time since the size of an array is fixed at compile time. Also for the non-confirming compilers that allow this (VLAs) to compile via an extension, `n` still needs to be initialized before your declaration.

Comment: n must be known at compile time if you're allocating from the stack. If you allocate from the heap, you can define n at runtime.

Comment: You cannot create arrays with a variable size in C++ without dynamically allocating memory (and consequently freeing it).

Comment: even with VLA extensions, `n` is uninitialized when used

Comment: I'd suggest reading a C++ book, surely your school's library has one.

Comment: Unrelated, is `#include < iostream >` legal? I popped the code into a formatter and it (and g++ because I figure it ought to know) screams bloody blue murder over the spaces.

Comment: @user4581301 the file would have to be named " iostream .h"

Comment: OK fixed it :).

Comment: ***the file would have to be named " iostream .h"*** No. That has not been true for a long time.

Comment: @Immac lose the .h and you're probably right. I think I'm going to have to queue this up for a read through of the the standard later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many others have mentioned in the comment section, another way (in case you want to stick with C array) would be to allocate the array dynamically on the heap.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {    
    int n;    
    cout << "please put the size of the array " ;    
    cin >> n; 
    int* Arr = new int[n]; //dynamically allocate an array to hold n int on the heap
    cout << "please enter array's elemets ";    
    for (int k=0; k<n ; k++) {    
        cin >> Arr[k];    
    }    
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){    
        cout << Arr[i] << endl;    
    }    
    delete [] Arr; //make sure to clean up the heap memories
}
```

Comment: Yup this is great :) I thought of using it like that :)

Comment: No this is not great. Is actually the opposite of great. In C++ you should never use raw `new`/`delete`.

Comment: what happens when you put this in a function in a bigger program and there is an exception between the `new[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: No, :( I don't know can you please guide me I am a beginner :)

Comment: That would be a memory leak because unlike variables/objects on stack, you'd need to call delete to free up the heap memory that you allocated.  If there are exceptions in between, your program will not get to the line of delete ..., thus a memory leak. as bolov suggested, it's safer and better to use std::vector. Hope this doesn't confuse you.

Comment: @bolov, is your comment due to the context that `Arr[n]` is just used in block scope or in general for all primitive types?

Answer (score 5):

`int Arr[n]` where `n` is not a compile time constant is illegal C++ code. Some compilers allow it as an extension (Variable Length Array).

Even with VLA extension, the code is invalid because `n` is uninitialized when used in your code.

First the real solution:

Use `std::vector` (tadaaa):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {    
    int n;
    std::vector<int> arr;

    std::cout << "please put the size of the array " ;    
    std::cin >> n;

    arr.reserve(n); // optional

    std::cout << "please enter array's elemets ";
    for (int k=0; k<n ; k++) {
        int elem;
        std::cin >> elem;
        arr.push_back(elem);
    }

    for (auto e : arr) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;    
    }    
}
```

If you need to compile against C++98 (wow):

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;    
}
```

or just:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;    
}
```

If you insist on using VLA (I recommend against it):

```
int n;
cout << "please put the size of the array " ;    
cin >> n;    
int Arr[n];    

cout << "please enter array's elemets ";    
for (int k=0; k<n ; k++) {    
    cin >> Arr[k];    
}    
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){    
    cout << Arr[i] << endl;    
}
```

Comment: For ( auto e : arr ) isn't allowed in c98 :(

Comment: Any particular reason you are using C++98?

Comment: Haha old PC and old IDE :(

Comment: @lazycracker that's no excuse. You can install a lightweight IDE.

Comment: OK gonna do this :) thnx BTW :')

Answer (score 0):

From [dcl.init#12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#12):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>   ([expr.ass]).

```
unsigned char c;
unsigned char d = c;        // OK, d has an indeterminate value
int e = d;                  // undefined behavior
```

Thus, in your code:

```
int n , Arr[n];
```

`n` has an indeterminate value until it's assigned in `cin >> n;`

using `n` with this indeterminate value (not value-/zero-/default-initialized and not assigned), can lead to undefined behavior.